# not all fields are inserted into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-services, soap

i have a simple soap web-service which has to get 3 items and insert them into table. But only first two fields are inserted. What is wrong?

**Here's the server:**

```
<?php
require_once '../scripts/database_connection.php';
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "1");

$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("appstatus", "urn:appstatus");

$server->register('getStatus',
    array("uid" => "xsd:decimal", "status" => "xsd:decimal", "comment" => "xsd:string"),
    array("return" => "xsd:string"),
    "urn:appstatus",
    "urn:appstatus#getStatus",
    "rpc",
    "encoded",
    "Get Status");
    function getStatus($uid,$status,$comment) {
       mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
       $query="INSERT INTO a_test (uid, approved, comment) VALUES ('{$uid}','{$status}','{$comment}')";
        mysql_query($query);
}

$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

**and this is the client:**

```
<?php 
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
//$result=$client->call('getStatus' array ('uid'=>3,'status'=>1));
$param = array( 'uid' => '33','status'=>'1','comment' => 'some comment');
$uid=$param['uid'];
$status=$param['status'];
$comment=$param['comment'];
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/webservice/getstatus.php?wsdl');
$response = $client->call('getStatus',$param);
if($client->fault) 
{ 
echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode."</p>"; 
echo "String: ".$client->faultstring; 
} 
else 
{ 
echo 'OK';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Sorry guys, everything is fine! Just be attentive when coding;) I renamed file, but kept editing its previous version.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in SQL query, third param is not a variable:

```
   $query="INSERT INTO a_test (uid, approved, comment) VALUES    
   ('{$uid}','{$status}','comment')";
```

replace with:

```
   $query="INSERT INTO a_test (uid, approved, comment) VALUES 
   ('{$uid}','{$status}','{$comment}')";
```